# Problems with logging out facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have problems with facebook logout. I have a button named log out. When this button is clicked it redirects the user to his home page after which the user can log out only with the options provided in facebook. But I want this to be done automatically right after the user clicks on log out.

```
$user            =   null; //facebook user uid
try{
    include_once "src/facebook.php";
}
catch(Exception $o)
{
    error_log($o);
}

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
  'cookie' => true,
  'fileUpload' => true,));



//Facebook Authentication part
$user       = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) 
{
  try {

    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
   error_log($e); 
    $user = null;
  }
}


$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope'         => "manage_pages",
            'redirect_uri'  => $fbconfig['baseurl']
        )
);

$logoutUrl  = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
```

//Index.php

```
   <?php if (!$user) { ?>
   FB Login Button
    <a href="<?=$loginUrl?>"><fb:login-button           
    scope="create_event,manage_pages,user_photos"> </fb:login-button></a>
   <?php } else { ?>
    <a href="<?=$logoutUrl?>">Facebook Logout</a>
   <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add your Domain URL at your app settings. And it will work like magic.